# How to copy common settings across all installed MS Office applications?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, default-settings

I have installed MS Office 2013 on my system with following applications:

- MS Word
- MS Outlook
- MS Excel

All these applications come up with their default settings. I want to change some of those settings. Some of those settings are common across all the applications.

So, I want a way so that, I will change the settings in one application (say Word) and those will be reflected in all other applications **if applicable and available**.

Right now, I do this all manually. I open Word, File-Options-Change the settings I want. Repeat the process with Excel and then Outlook.

Is there a way to do this in some automated way? At least for Word and Outlook?

Examples of some common settings:

- Show mini toolbar on selection
- Enable live preview
- Font settings (name, size etc)
- Office Theme
- Spelling and Auto correct
- Customize Ribbon
- Quick access toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the Office settings for current user are mostly saved in Registry key settings. For the feature you mentioned above, some of them are not able to control in Office level at once. We can just configure the setting for specific products one by one.

For example, about **Show mini toolbar on selection** and **Enable live preview**, we can create the setting registry under specific product instead of the whole Office level to control it:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars\Word 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars\Excel
```

Value: **allowselectionfloaties**   set 0 to disable it, 1 to enable it.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options
```

Value: **livepreview**     set 0 to disable it, 1 to enable it.

About the **default Font settings** in Word and Outlook, we also need to configure it for specific products. We can do the following settings about the default Font for different Office applications:

Word 2016:

- Open Word and start with a clean new document.
- Hit CTRL-D to start the Font settings.
- Set your Font of choice and hit “Set as Default”
- “Save as” the document to Normal.dotm
- Copy this Normal.dotm file to “%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm" and replace the old one.

Outlook 2016:

- Set the font in Outlook on a clean machine by going to Options -> Stationary and fonts… in Outlook. Close Outlook.
- On this Machine, go to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings".
- Export by right click on the MailSettings folder.
- Then you can push/import this MailSettings registry value to your wanted computer.
- You can set the MailSettings above to the path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings
  The main registry values are:

  ```
  Value name: “ComposeFontComplex”
  Value name: “ComposeFontSimple”
  Value name: “CReplyFontComplex”
  Value name: “ReplyFontSimple”
  Value name: “TextFontComplex”
  Value name: “TextFontSimple”
  ```

About **Office Theme** and **AutoCorrect** settings, we can use registry settings to set it at once:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\15.0\common

Value: **default ui theme**      0 for White, 1 for Light Grey, 2 for Dark Grey.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\AutoCorrect
```

For Ribbon and Quick Access Toolbar, it also needs to configured for specific apps.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts +1, but this needs to be worked one by one. This is not what I am looking for.